# how to exclude multiple directories with pcregrep?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, pcre

I'm trying to exclude multiple directories from search result of `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep --exclude_dir=^\./(foo/abc|bar/cde)$ --recursive --regex alpha .
```

In other words, I want to find all files that contain `alpha`, and I want to ignore `./foo/abc/*` and `./bar/cde/*` files during search. Doesn't work, directories are not being excluded. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern of `--exclude_dir` matches only the directory name, not the whole path.
Therefore you cannot have `/` inside the pattern. If the directory names you want to exclude are unique, you can use:

```
pcregrep --exclude_dir='^abc|cde$' -r alpha .
```

Please note that you often need to surround the pattern with `'` or using any other quotation/escaping mechanism. In most cases, you can leave out `--regex=`.

If you are using `zsh` as your shell and have EXTENDED_GLOB set, you can use the following solution to exclude whole paths:

```
pcregrep alpha **/*~(foo/abc/*|bar/cde/*)(.)
```

---

However, the feature you request can easily be implemented into pcregrep:
Download its source ([pcre library](http://www.pcre.org/)) and change

```
pcre_exec(exclude_dir_compiled, NULL, nextfile, nflen, 0, 0, NULL, 0)
```

in file `pcregrep.c` to

```
pcre_exec(exclude_dir_compiled, NULL, buffer,  (int) strlen(buffer), 0, 0, NULL, 0)
```

Please note that this change is not backward compatible. The best way would be to introduce a new `--exclude_path` flag.

Comment: @yegor256 pcregrep can easily be changed so that it supports what you want. See my updated answer.